# Python combine multiple projects to one global project

Tags: python, python-venv, multiple-projects

I was wondering how I can combine multiple projects, each of them within an own virtual environment, to one global project.

For example this structure:

```
Python
|
|-- Send_Mails
|   |-venv
|   |-main.py
|
|-- Create_Files
|   |-venv
|   |-main.py
|
|-- Scrape_Web
|   |-venv
|   |-main.py
```

Each project has it own purpose, but from time to time I need a `Send_Mails` function within `Create_Files`. I wasn't able to simply import the send mail function from `Send_Mails` inside of `Create_Files` due to a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

What is the trick to do this?

Comment: I would rather copy code to new single venv

Comment: Extract reusable code into libraries. Install those libraries (as "editable") into each virtual environment as needed.

Comment: Is there no other way to keep the code up to date even if I make changes? Manually copying the code seems error prone in case I forget to copy something.

Comment: why would you do that? a single env is the way to go.

Comment: For example Send_Mails is used in multiple other Projects, it is much clearer to use one Code from one location rather then Copy and Paste it in each Project. But each Project is cleaner within a own venv. @sinoroc thanks, I didn't know the "editable" option, this could be the solution I was looking for.